# selenium webdriverwait for a timer which is innerText

Tags: c#, selenium, timer

Hi i am having trouble with making this code work and i need help.
the html code is

```
<span id="banner">Rolling in 10.00...</span>
```

this "Rolling in 10.00..." is an innerText and the 10.00 is a timer that means it will keep running until 0. I am interested in trying to run a code when the timer is at 20.00. example

```
<span id="banner">Rolling in 20.00...</span>
```

however i am having lots of trouble. this are some codes that work but have socket exception error (http://puu.sh/mubug/c33d8501bf.png)

```
public void waitroller2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start roller timer");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        IWebElement banner = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("banner")));

        watch.Start();
        do
        {
            if (banner.Text.Equals("Rolling in 20.00..."))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("roller ended");
                return;
            }
        } while (watch.Elapsed.Seconds < 1000);

        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

this method does not work at all

```
public void waitroller1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("waitroller");
        new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(rolling,"Rolling in 20.00..."));
        Console.WriteLine("roller end");
    }
```

i think the main problem is when i keep using this webdriverwait for long time it is not working have socket problem . pls i need help anyone can teach me how do it

Comment: you have void function what you returning ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
try
{
    string timeToWait = new String(driver.FindElement(By.Id("banner")).Text.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()).Substring(0,2);

    int ttw = Convert.ToInt32(timeToWait);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ttw * 1000);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
```

Comment: i am not sure what you doing my freiend can you explain

Comment: if i understand you correct you need to wait for time that written in the innerText, so i taking the string get from it the time and making the program to wait.

Comment: yes my friend but your code instantly loops very fast my friend i need to keep using this . meaning to say when the innertext is "Rolling in 20.00..." , i perform action and wait for the next "Rolling in 20.00..."

Comment: if you its 10 and you want 20 you can always add to sleep (ttw * 2000)

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need.

```
        IWebElement banner = driver.FindElement(By.Id("banner")).Text;
        bool status = false;
        int tryTimes = 15;

        do
        {
            if (banner.Text.Equals("Rolling in 20.00..."))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("roller ended");
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                banner = driver.FindElement(By.Id("banner")).Text;
                tryTimes--;
            }
        } while (!status && tryTimes > 0);
```